# $("a").href always returns absolute URL even when href attribute is relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to rewrite some links on my page so that I make them absolute, but only if they are not already absolute.

I am using jQuery, and doing something like this:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if (!this.href.startsWith("http")) {
        this.href = "http://blah.com" + this.href
    }
});
```

Unexpectedly (to me) `this.href` always returns an absolute URL (`http://blah.com/somePath`) even when the page source shows that the URL is relative (`/somePath`).

How can I get the 'real' value (as it appears in the page source) of an `href`?

I have only tried this in Firefox 19.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the Anchor element will always resolve the whole URL. You can use the jQuery function `attr` to get just the contents of the attribute, like so

```
$('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the attribute value instead of the href property

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (!href.startsWith("http")) {
        $(this).attr('href', "http://blah.com" + href);
    }
});
```

Try a more simplified version

```
$("a:not([href^=http])").attr('href', function (i, href) {
    return "http://blah.com" + href
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kn6CB/)